# Compressed image transfer syntax

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a point grey chamelon ieeee1394 camera. I'm  able to get the images with camera1394 node through image_transport method. I'm taking the raw image from /camera/image_color node inside class with standart image_transport subscribe.

```
 image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
 image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("camera/image_color", 1, &ImageGate::readImage(), this );
```

Here readImage(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg) is defined.

But when I try to get the compressed image I did not make it. I tried something like:

```
image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe<sensor_msgs::CompressedImage>("camera/image_color", 1, &ImageGate::readImage(), this );
```

But it didn't work like this. Also I didn't find the way within compressed image tutorial.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46286/compressed-image-transfer-syntax/) by [cheour](https://answers.ros.org/users/2230/cheour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2012-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a problem like that a while ago and it was because the compressed image plugin wasn't built. Maybe try:

```
rosmake compressed_image_transport
```

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0